# CSV Viewers which can handle large files (37mb) and don't mess with formatting

Tags: windows, csv

I have a 37mb csv file that I want to view in a spreadsheet like format. Excel screws with my formatting too much, so I want something else. What viewers (for windows) will be able to handle a large csv efficiently and not mess with the data at all? (I don't care about editing functionality). The viewer also has to be able to handle newlines within double quoted fields.

Comment: There is a Convert to fixed width and Convert to CSV feature in UltraEdit. This text editor can open very large files and may do what you need. You can start with a full function trial issue to see if it does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice Calc (https://www.libreoffice.org/) or Tad (https://www.tadviewer.com/).

Below the LibreOffice Calc CSV open window.

[image]

An important note for Calc: when you open a CSV, especially the firs time, set the field type for all field to text (see the image below). In this way there is no interpretation of dates, floating, and you will have in output what you have in input.

[image]

Comment: I think I tried libreoffice, but I'm pretty sure that it reformated my dates

Comment: @StormFalcon I have edited my answer and added a note to block every field type inferencing

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: (1) The [max number of rows in Libre Calc](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Calc/022#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20maximum%20number,than%201%20billion%20cells%29%3B) is 1,048,576 (2^20), so it will only allow you to interact with a portion of CSV files exceeding this size, (2) Tad did fine with 100-300MB files, but could not open a 34GB file within 12 minutes on my 16GB RAM laptop, (3) Ultimately, I used VSCode + Python + Dask to process the 34GB CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) may be worth a shot, but getting the contents to display as you'd want may require a plugin ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554748/notepad-formatting-data-into-actual-table-columns) touches on that).